# asp.net core - what are the differences of these MapRazorPages() calls?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-3.0

**Method 1**

In ASP.NET Core 3.x, we add endpoints for Razor Pages with

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint =>
{
    endpoint.MapRazorPages();
});
```

**Method 2**

In the ASP.NET Core 6 Web App template (minimal hosting model), this has been changed to:

```
app.MapRazorPages();
```

From MS [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#conventional-routing):

> Apps typically don't need to call UseRouting or UseEndpoints. WebApplicationBuilder configures a middleware pipeline that wraps middleware added in Program.cs with UseRouting and UseEndpoints. For more information, see Routing in ASP.NET Core.

My questions are:

1. Do the 2 method calls above have the same effect?
2. Am I correct to assume that the second way (i.e. `app.MapRazorPages()`) is possible due to the middleware pipeline configuration by `WebApplicationBuilder`? (see snippet from MS docs above).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the ans is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. They are using the same method.

Details you could see below explain:

endpoint.MapRazorPages():

[image]

app.MapRazorPages();:

[image: });]

Comment: thanks. would you be able to advise on my second question?